# What was changed in java so synthetic methods were removed?

Tags: java

I've tried to google but didn't find any details about the next:

In pre-11 java we had synthetic methods which were added by the compiler to bind private fields from outer classes and inner classes. Sounds logical, since after compilation inner classes contain a link to the outer class to have an access to it. So to access a private member - kind of synthetic getters were created.

The question is: how java-11 + handle it? Synthetic methods are removed. How do they achieve access to private?

Comment: See [JEP 181: Nest-Based Access Control](https://openjdk.org/jeps/181).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the Java Virtual Machine was updated in Java 11, to allow private fields in outer classes to be accessed "directly".

You can compare [JVMS 11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/index.html) and [JVMS 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/index.html).

First, notice that sections [4.7.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.28) and [4.7.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.29) are added, which describe the `NestHost` and `NestMembers` attributes in the class file format. When you compile a nested class like this for example:

```
public class Outer {

    private int x;

    public class Inner {
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

The `NestHost` attribute of the Outer$Inner.class file will record its outer class, `Outer`. And the `NestMembers` attribute of the Outer.class file will record the inner class, `Outer$Inner`.

Second, a few more paragraphs are added to the [Access Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.4) section to make use of the `NestHost` and `NestMembers` attributes. This is what it says in Java 11:

> A field or method R is accessible to a class or interface D if and
> only if any of the following is true:
>
> - [...]
> - R is `private` and is declared by a class or interface C that belongs to the same nest as D, according to the nestmate test below.
>
> If R is not accessible to D, then:
>
> - [...]
> - If R is `private`, then the nestmate test failed, and access control fails for the same reason.

Whereas in Java 10, [it only says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.4):

> A field or method R is accessible to a class or interface D if and
> only if any of the following is true:
>
> - [...]
> - R is `private` and is declared in D.

The "nestmate test" is a bit long, so I am not going to quote it here. The important part is that it takes the `NestHost` of the classes into account.

Going back to the code above, in Java 10, the access control rules of the JVM says that `x` is not accessible from `Inner`, so the compiler had to synthesise an extra method so that `Inner` can access it. In Java 11, the rules now say that `x` is accessible from `Inner`, so the access to `x` can be simply compiled to a `getfield` instruction.